# How to make addition dynamically in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is my xml :

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "ISO-8859-1"?>
 <List>
  <Customer>
    <client name="Jean Charles" />
    <transaction amount="500" />
    <question> What is the latest brand </question>
    <transaction amount="1200" />
  </Customer>
 <Customer>
  <client name="Philippe" />
  <transaction amount="600" />
  <transaction amount="800" />
  <question> Where can I find the 2002 model </question>
  <transaction amount="2000" />
</Customer>
</List>
```

And XSLT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
 <body>
 <h2>Customer transaction</h2>
   <table border="1">
     <xsl:for-each select="List/Customer">
     <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="client/@name"/></td>
    <xsl:for-each select="transaction">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@amount"/></td>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But i need output of each customer transaction amount total . example for first customer 500+1200 = 1700.

Can any one please help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [the `sum` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-sum):

```
<xsl:for-each select="List/Customer">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="client/@name"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(transaction/@amount)" /></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```